# Check which value contains property Java WebDriver

Tags: java, junit, webdriver

I'm almost do NOT know Java, but I'm learning and have to write some tests in it using WebDriver & jUnit :) I have already performed some, looks like:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class MyTests {

  @BeforeClass
  public static void allTestsStarted() {
    System.out.println("All tests started");
  }

  @org.junit.Test
  public void testImagePresence() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    try {
        driver = WebDriverHelper.create("https://here.goes.path.to.my.site");

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("myImage"));
        String imageSrc = element.getAttribute("src");

        Assert.assertNotNull(imageSrc);

    } finally {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }
  }

  # and more and more lines like these :)
}
```

All works fine :) Now I wanna create test that will check which value now contains my property... Maybe it's not clear, example: one element in one moment of time may contains *display: block*, and other time it may be *display: none*... So how it's gonna look like in Java? Just interesting is it possible or not, so please... Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, since SO has encouraged users to answer our own questions - I'll do it :) All I had to do is simplify my code a bit :) I wrote two CSS rules: `.dispBlock { display:block }` and `.dispNone { display:none }` instead inline css and than in test just checked - visible it or not... Looks like:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.className("dispBlock"));
Assert.assertEquals(true, el.isDisplayed());
```

Of course, on page may be a few elements with that class, but as a first step for learning it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "Attributes".
you can get those using getAttribute: e.g element.getAttribute("display");

Comment: yeah, as you can see I had used that in my code already, but the question is - what am I supposed to do next? It's gonna be something like  _Assert.assertNot block/none (display)_ ...